# if service is in manual mode then the .vbs file shouldn't start the service

Tags: web-services, batch-file

Please find the below WebStart.cmd code:

Cureently the code is starting the service NetworkRequestWorkflow. But in future mode of operation, this service would be set in Manual mode and .vbs should not start this service automatically. Please help me in getting it done as expected.

```
setlocal
set LogDir="D:\Program Files (x86)\Bell\NetReq\Data\WebStartup.log"
PROMPT $P $D $T $G

REM Make sure that the services is set to automatic before doing iisreset   /start
@echo . >> %LogDir%

sc config msftpsvc start= auto >> %LogDir%
sc config smtpsvc start= auto >> %LogDir%
sc config w3svc start= auto >> %LogDir%

echo Start Web Server and related process > %LogDir%
PROMPT >> %LogDir%

iisreset /start /rebootonerror  >> %LogDir%
iisreset /status >> %LogDir%

REM added as part of NETREQ Upgrade Phase-1 project
echo Start NetReq Workflow Service > %LogDir%
@echo Environment - %COMPUTERNAME% >> %LogDir%
NET START "NetworkRequestWorkFlow" >> %LogDir%
NET START  >> %LogDir%
@echo . >> %LogDir%

endlocal
```

Comment: Why not just remove/comment out the command which starts the service?

Comment: Your code is batch. Not Vbscript.  So your thread title and description are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sc qc` to query the service configuration and pipe it to `find` to filter by `"DEMAND_START"`:

```
sc qc NetworkRequestWorkflow | find "DEMAND_START">nul
if not errorlevel 1 (
    echo The service is in MANUAL start mode
    ...............
    ...............
) else (
    sc start NetworkRequestWorkflow
    ...............
    ...............
)
```